# Connecting to MYSQL of and domain database

Tags: mysql, dns, database-connection

I have one domain like www.testme.com and at the hosting place there is a database (MYSQL). Now I am using internet on my home system and like to connect that database using MYSQL Query Browser.  Can its possible?

Comment: kindly go to the following link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you need to enable remote access to the MySQL Database. Something like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO user@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Where `foo` is the database name, `user` is the username you use to connect to the database and `1.2.3.4` is your current IP address at home.

Obviously, your hosting provider should allow remote connections to port 3306 (usually MySQL runs on this port).